# Activerecord: Getting a type error when using alias for a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table with items, and a table with item characteristics.
Corresponding models:

```
    class Characteristic < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :item
    end

    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :characteristics
    end
```

Each characteristic has it's name (i.e. 'price'), value, an a reference to an item.
I need to select items by multiple characteristics, say, price = 100 and weight = 50. For this, i need to join tables twice, like this:

```
    Item.joins('INNER JOIN characteristics c1 ON c1.item_id = items.id').
    joins('INNER JOIN characteristics c2 ON c2.item_id = items.id').
    where('c1' => {name: 'price', value: '100'}, 
    'c2' => {name: 'weight', value: '50'})
```

and this is where the problem is. Characteristic's value is stored in database as string, and when i try to compare it to an integer, or range, I get a type conversion error. But when i don't use an alias for a table, there is no error.
So, the code below works:

```
    Item.joins('INNER JOIN "characteristics" ON "characteristics"."item_id" = "items"."id"').
    where(characteristics: {characteristic_type_id: 223, value: 380})
```

But this one does not:

```
    Item.joins('INNER JOIN "characteristics" c1 ON c1."item_id" = "items"."id"').
    where(c1: {characteristic_type_id: 223, value: 380})
```

So how can I select items with, say, price in 50..100 and color 'brown'?

UPD:
  neither of above code works, actually. First one does not produce an SQL error, but it does the wrong thing. It just quotes the value so it becomes string. I.e.

```
    where(c1: {value: 10..15})
```

becomes

```
    WHERE ("c1"."value" BETWEEN '10' AND '15')
```

which is, obviously, not what I really want
So I decided do add one more field to characteristics, value_f:decimal{8,2} to hold the numeric value of characteristic. I also added

```
    after_validation do
      self.value_f = value.to_f
    end
```

to characteristic's model. So, when I want to compare a value to a number, I just use value_f instead.

Comment: Someone had a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375627/rails-query-join-association-table-with-alias/29392498#29392498

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Item.joins(:characteristics).where(characteristics: [{name: 'price', value: '100'},{name: 'weight', value: '50'}] )
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column items.item_id does not exist
                                                            
: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "characteristics" ON "characteristics"."item_id" = "items"."id" WHERE "items"."item_id" IN ('---
:characteristic_type_id: 223
:value: ''380''
', '---
:characteristic_type_id: 222
:value: ''11,0''
')  Feels like we just need to replace "items"."item_id" with something more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
[Postgresql. CREATE CAST 'character varying' to 'integer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760759/postgresql-create-cast-character-varying-to-integer)

```
    CREATE CAST (varchar AS integer) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

Still have to figure out how to execute this on Heroku, but that's a different question